# Using VBA Code To Customize SQL Query

Tags: sql, vba, excel, powerquery

Currently i am working on an Excel workbook connected to a sql query as a source of data using power query
this sql query contains a date value
i need to add a vba code that makes the users able to customize the date value in the sql query

to make my self more clear, for example the sql query contains this code,I can of course change it manually, But what i need is to add a button or something to the sheet to make users able to change the dat period

Ex. 
DECLARE @DT_FROM NVARCHAR(23); SET @DT_FROM = N'2018-03-29';
DECLARE @DT_TO NVARCHAR(23); SET @DT_TO = N'2018-03-29';

is that possible?
Thanks
Regards

Comment: If you are using Power Query, open the `Advanced Editor` and copy the whole `M code` and paste it in your description for reference. You can convert your query to a `Function` and `invoke` it accepting the `date parameters` from the cells.

Comment: Or use my answer here and set two parameter variables (?,?) pulling from the sheet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49490189/export-stored-procedure-result-set-to-excel-in-ssms/49492612#49492612

Comment: Thanks, But that was not exactly what i meant..look i'll explain it another way..can i create a button or drop down list or any kind of use input that can changes a statement on SQL query, Using VBA?

Answer (score 0):

You can give a name to a cell, e.g. CELLNAME (menu tab Formulas -> Name Manager).
Then you can read value from such cell into Power Query using following pattern

```
Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="CELLNAME"]}[Content]{0}[Column1]
```

Assume you created two names "FROM", "TO", then you can build a following string in Power Query:

```
="DECLARE @DT_FROM NVARCHAR(23); SET @DT_FROM = N'" & 
    Date.ToText( Date.From( Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="FROM"]}[Content]{0}[Column1] ), 
                 "yyyy-mm-dd" ) & 
    "'; DECLARE @DT_TO NVARCHAR(23); SET @DT_TO = N'" & 
    Date.ToText( Date.From( Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="TO"]}[Content]{0}[Column1] ), 
                 "yyyy-mm-dd" ) & "';"
```

How you change values in those cell is up to you - macro or direct input.