# Need a query to view certain columns of multiple tables and stored procedure in Excel sheet

Tags: sql, excel, database, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

Need a query to view certain columns of multiple tables and stored procedures in a single Excel sheet as a table, which is connected to the database `IDS_SAF` in SQL Server 2014.

I have two question here,

1. How to write a stored procedure to generate the output as stated in the screenshot.
2. How to link that stored procedure to the Excel sheet, so that I get all the data based on the stored procedure written.

The `Select` query for each column are provided below. I don't know how to join those separate statements to make a single query. The application used is Excel 2016.

The columns in the screenshot below are the ones I want in Excel:

[image: These are the columns I want together]..

As said, I'll attach the SQL select query for each of the columns.

```
SELECT 
    [VV_Code],
    [Vessel_Code],
    [Arrival_Date],
    [Terminal_code]
FROM
    [IDS_SAF].[dbo].[Vessel_Voyage]
```

From the `[dbo].[Vessel_Voyage]` table, we have `Vessel_Code` instead of `Vessel_Name`. There is a separate table for `Vessel_Name` which is based on the `Vessel_Code`. But we need to get only the `Vessel_Name` column in the Excel.

```
SELECT 
    [Vessel_Code],
    [Vessel_Name]
FROM
    [IDS_SAF].[dbo].[Vessel]
```

The select query for `VIR NOS` is listed below,

```
SELECT 
    [VV_CODE],
    [VIR_NO]
FROM
    [IDS_SAF].[dbo].[IGM]
```

The total index column is defined to be `BL_Count` and it doesn't have a table but a stored procedure. The code is below,

```
USE [IDS_SAF]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO


CREATE PROC [dbo].[BL_COUNT]
    @VV_CODE VARCHAR(20)
AS
    SELECT
        'Total Bill Of Ladings' as 'BL Count',
        COUNT(BL_NO) as 'Total BLs'
    FROM
        BL_DATA
    WHERE
        VV_CODE = @VV_CODE AND
        ISNULL(UNUSED_FLAG, '') <> '1'
```

Same way, the Imp containers column have two sections of count details in them based on the container size (20FT and 40FT). The Total Number of Containers must be the total of these both. We have stored procedure for this as well.

```
USE [IDS_SAF]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO


CREATE PROC [dbo].[BL_CONTAINER_GET_NO_OF_CONTAINERS]
    @VV_CODE VARCHAR(10),
    @BL_NO VARCHAR(30)
AS
    SELECT
        CONTAINER_SIZE_DESCRIPTION,
        (SELECT COUNT(CONTAINER_SIZE_CODE) FROM BL_CONTAINER
        WHERE BL_NO = BC.BL_NO AND CONTAINER_SIZE_CODE = BC.CONTAINER_SIZE_CODE) AS SIZE_COUNT

    FROM
        BL_CONTAINER BC, CONTAINER_SIZE CS
    WHERE

    BL_NO = @BL_NO AND
    VV_CODE = @VV_CODE AND
    BC.CONTAINER_SIZE_CODE = CS.CONTAINER_SIZE_CODE
    GROUP BY CONTAINER_SIZE_DESCRIPTION, BL_NO, BC.CONTAINER_SIZE_CODE

GO
```

Based on these select statements of tables and stored procedures, I am in need of a query which helps in getting these columns together as a table.

Kindly help me please. Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: Not going to read all that but can you not write a new stored procedure that performs a join between the two tables of interest and pulls back the columns you want? Then execute that sp from Excel ? You can pick up a parameter/parameters from the sheet. See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49490189/export-stored-procedure-result-set-to-excel-in-ssms. Hope that is clear.

Comment: I am new to coding... Just learning... Managed to find the code needed to write the query... But I don't yet know to write stored procedures.. So needed help @QHarr

Comment: I would split this into two questions. Post the first question as how to write a stored procedure to generate the output as stated above. 
Post a new question on how to execute that stored procedure from Excel picking up the parameter from the sheet. You could refer to my answer for the latter question and update your above question for the former. That is just my thought. One of the SQL gurus will write a better optimized query for you than I could in terms of a stored procedure according to the distribution of W_Codes  and any existing indexes to >> better query plans.

Comment: That's great to hear... I'll do that..! Thank you for you help..!!

Comment: Make sure that it is clear it is a parameter based sp taking input parameter W_Code... to get a  really decent answer information about existing indexes and distribution stats on W_Codes might be useful but the SQL peeps will know how best to frame that.

Comment: And check you have permissions to either create and/or execute sps against the database (s) in question. Apologies, I misquoted the number of tables involved in my original comment.

Comment: Ya sure... It is enough if I get all the data by the stored procedure..! Thank you so much for your time... It made me understand what my requirement actually was..! Thank you..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to write the stored procedure and it's working. Posting it for any further reference !

```
select 
VVO.VV_CODE, 
V.Vessel_name, 
VVO.Arrival_date, 
isnull(IGM.VIR_NO,'NULL') as VIR_NO, 
isnull(VVO.TERMINAL_CODE,'NULL') as TERMINAL_CODE,
(SELECT
COUNT(BL_NO)
FROM
BL_DATA
WHERE
VV_CODE = VVO.VV_CODE) as TOTAL_INDEX,
(select CAST(COUNT(VV_CODE) as int) from BL_Container  where Container_Size_Code = 19 and BL_Container.VV_CODE = VVO.VV_CODE ) as TWENTY_FT,
(select CAST(COUNT(VV_CODE) as int) from BL_Container  where Container_Size_Code = 20 and BL_Container.VV_CODE = VVO.VV_CODE ) as FOURTY_FT,
(select CAST(COUNT(VV_CODE) as int) from BL_Container  where (Container_Size_Code = 20 or Container_Size_Code = 19) and BL_Container.VV_CODE = VVO.VV_CODE ) as Total_No_of_Cntrs,
(Select((select cast(COUNT(VV_CODE) as float) from BL_Container where Container_Size_Code = 19 and BL_Container.VV_CODE = VVO.VV_CODE)/2 + (select COUNT(VV_CODE) from BL_Container where Container_Size_Code = 20 and BL_Container.VV_CODE = VVO.VV_CODE))) as Total_FFE
from Vessel_voyage VVO, Vessel V, IGM where V.Vessel_code = substring(VVO.VV_CODE,1,3) and VVO.VV_CODE = IGM.VV_CODE
```

Thank you for the one's who tried..!!